# Unable to install ubuntu on HP laptop

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

My PC:
HP Spectre 13-v001ur (ENERGY STAR)
Only USB 3.1 (Type-C).

I downloaded from official website Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 ISO Image.
Successfully burned it via Rufus ( also tried Unetboon ). I tried with different options like MBR for Bios and UEFI, MBR for UEFI, and GPT for UEFI.
After that, I go to BIOS and changed Boot options to USB.
Bios successfully loaded from USB device, after that i choose "Run Ubuntu without installation".
Ubuntu starts... loading...loading.. and failed.
Error: "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system"
The same error if I choose "Install Ubuntu"

Note: I used different USB devices.
[Error while loading without installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbv5r.jpg)

Comment: Try disabling USB 3.0 from BIOS

Comment: I don't have this option in BIOS. I have only Boot from USB Enable/Disable